# Distributing n objects among p groups of q members

Tags: algorithm, math

I have not been able to find the answer to this exact problem:

Given `n` objects for `n` an integer at least 2, I need to distribute them equally between `p` groups where `p` greater than or equal to 2 and `n` greater than or equal to `p`, where, by 'equally', I mean the following: Each group contains `q` members; `q` at least 1. The number of members of a group determines a 'weight' for the group, since the `n` objects should be distributed such that larger groups (i.e. more members) get more objects. However, each group must receive at least one object.

Example: Given `n=5` objects and two groups `p_1` and `p_2` with `q_1=1` and `q_2=9`, `p_1` gets 1 object and `p_2` 4.

Comment: ... The question being, 'Is there an algorithm for achieving such a distribution?'.

Comment: What are the inputs? You're specifying n and p? And to be clear, it sounds like "equally" doesn't matter; i.e. the groups are different sizes?

Comment: I'm unclear on what q_2 = 9 means in your example?

Comment: Distribution should be according to 'size' of a group which is determined by the number of members.
Inputs are n, p_i (i groups) and q_i (q members of group p_i).
q_2=9 means 9 members of group p_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. You probably want this:

```
// add 1 to each group and subtract from n
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    group[i] = 1;
n -= p;

while (n > 0)
{
    // find i, such that q[i] / group[i] is maximum
    int imax = 0;
    double max = q[0] / group[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < p; ++i)
    {
        if (q[i] / group[i] > max)
        {
            max = q[i] / group[i];
            imax = i;
        }
    }
    ++group[imax];
    --n;
}
```

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method

Comment: Yes, I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, without the demand that each group must have at least one object:

uniformly draw an integer between 1 and `sum(q_n)=q_1+q_2+...+q_n`

if the integer falls between `sum(q_i)` and and `sum(q_{i+1})`, then add one object to group `i`.

Now to make sure each group has one object, simply add one object to each group (it doesn't change the weighted distribution).